# LibreBase does not work with 20.04

Tags: 20.04, libreoffice, 20.10

LibreOffice Base version: 6.4.6.2 of LibreOffice does not work with Ubuntu 20.04. Everything was fine with 18.04.

[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

You need to install an additional package:

```
sudo apt install libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb
```

Then you'll be able to connect to your already existing database.

Comment: Installed but how to connect?

Comment: Just open the database you want to connect to again, for me this just worked.

Comment: It did not work with existing db. I created new and from the new was able to open existiong.

Comment: It was unexpected for me too, so I have reported [bug 1915637](https://pad.lv/1915637) to LaunchPad. On my fresh 20.04 LTS and 20.10 VM your method works.

Comment: Sorry @mook765, removed comment